# Why does the formulation of the SVM problem has the bias (something we try to optimize) as a part of the constraint?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, optimization, convex

The common formulation of the SVM problem is

$$\min_{\theta, \theta_0}\frac{1}{2}||\theta||^2$$
$$\text{ subject to: } y^{(t)}(\theta \cdot x^{(t)} + \theta_0) \geq 1, \ t=1,...,n,$$

However, it seems to be unnatural that $\theta_0$ (something we try to optimize) is a part of the constraint, but it doesn't appear in the objective.

Is this natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because SVM is trying to maximize the margin between supporting planes. The margin is $2\over||\theta||$, which is the distance between the supporting hyperplanes. Distance between parallel hyperplanes is $\frac{\text{bias difference}}{||\text{normal vector}||}$, where normal vector is $\theta$ here. For classes $1,-1$ the bias terms are $1-\theta_0$ and $-1-\theta_0$, so their difference is $2$. Maximizing this term is equivalent to minimizing $\frac{||\theta||^2}{2}$.